# FFmpeg concat results in DTS out of order

Tags: ffmpeg

Following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31691943/ffmpeg-concat-poduces-dts-out-of-order-errors

I tried to concat 4 clips made by geforce experience in-game features, it resulted in `DTS out of order sync` issues, and even after tweaking (adding `-video_track_timescale 90000`), the desync still occurs.

Script

```
@echo off
Title Converting to mpegts
ffmpeg -i "1.mp4" -c copy -video_track_timescale 90000 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate1.ts
ffmpeg -i "2.mp4" -c copy -video_track_timescale 90000 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate2.ts
ffmpeg -i "3.mp4" -c copy -video_track_timescale 90000 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate3.ts
ffmpeg -i "4.mp4" -c copy -video_track_timescale 90000 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate4.ts
ffmpeg -i "5.mp4" -c copy -video_track_timescale 90000 -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts intermediate5.ts

Title Merging Videos
ffmpeg -i "concat:intermediate1.ts|intermediate2.ts|intermediate3.ts|intermediate4.ts|intermediate5.ts" -c copy -video_track_timescale 90000 -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc "Merged.mp4"

PAUSE
```

Errors :

```
[mpegts @ 000001e550c9a740] DTS 128882 < 5293388 out of orderitrate=48489.8kbits/s speed= 104x
[mpegts @ 000001e550c9a740] DTS 126000 < 2053347 out of order
[mpegts @ 000001e550c9a740] DTS 127439 < 2092407 out of order
[mpegts @ 000001e550c9a740] DTS 126000 < 1559930 out of order
```

Infos from few clips :

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2019-12-13T18:23:12.000000Z
    date            : 2019
  Duration: 00:00:57.43, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 47904 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt470m), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 47701 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-12-13T18:23:12.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 196 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-12-13T18:23:12.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler


Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp41isom
    creation_time   : 2019-12-13T18:22:06.000000Z
    date            : 2019
  Duration: 00:00:21.43, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 49275 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt470m), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 49071 kb/s, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 60k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-12-13T18:22:06.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 196 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-12-13T18:22:06.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```